# Get a line in a string at a particular offset

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a string that I am looping through character by character. I know the offset of the character in the string but I don't know the line.

What I would like to do is get the line text at a particular offset. how can I do so?

```
I like to 
eat pizza
do you?
```

For the above example, If I want the line at offset `15` I would get the following line `eat pizza`.

Comment: Interesting one. Maybe you could split at newlines, then loop through the resulting array adding up the lengths of the lines until you get to the offset you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my implementation (https://jsfiddle.net/Lgb3qncu/1/):

```js
function findLine(str, idx) {
  var first = str.substring(0, idx);
  var last = str.substring(idx);

  var firstNewLine = first.lastIndexOf("\n");

  var secondNewLine = last.indexOf("\n");

  if ( secondNewLine == -1 ) {
    secondNewLine = last.length;
  }

  return str.substring(firstNewLine+1, idx+secondNewLine);
}


var str =
`I like to 
eat pizza
do you?`;
console.log(findLine(str, 15));
```

Comment: Personally, I like this [minified version](https://jsfiddle.net/jlam55555/7q9c5gfg/) of your function :)

Comment: Oops didn't realize I took off that `if` statement. Well, for all cases except when the match is on the last line, it should work ... right? And it's about 25% of the original length

Comment: Correct @JonathanLam

Answer (score 3):

You can try this code.

What it does is go through each character of each line, decreasing `offset` until it reaches 0. Then it prints out the line that it is on.

```js
function getLine(str, off) {
  var lines = string.split("\n");
  for(line in lines)
    for(var i = 0; i < lines[line].length; i++)
      if(--off == 0)
        return lines[line];
}

var string =
`I like to 
eat pizza
do you?`;
console.log(getLine(string, 15));
```

Comment: I see "Uncaught ReferenceError: offset is not defined".

Comment: @FrankerZ Oops I had the variable name wrong. It'll work now

Comment: I like your implementation too =)

Comment: I am not sure if it is true or not, but this seems like it would get slower on larger files, with loops... Maybe I am wrong?

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn There is one loop iteration for a count of `offset` characters. Therefore, for *very large files* it might be slow. But for most purposes, this should work just fine.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn In other words, there is one loop for every line, and one loop for every character per line. In other words, one loop per character.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution.

```
public static String getString(String str, int offSet) {
    String array[] = str.split("\\n");

    for (int index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {

        if (array[index].length() >= offSet)
            return array[index];
        else
            offSet = offSet - array[index].length();

    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: @FrankerZ its java.

Comment: Was curious, because the post was tagged javascript/typescript.

Answer (score 0):

java-script solution for this.

```
function getString(str,offSet){
   var array = str.split("\n"); 
   for (index = 0; index < array.length; index++) { 
        if(array[index].length >=offSet)
           return array[index];
        else
           offSet = offSet -  array[index].length;                               
   }
   return null;
}
```